# Display multiple data and timestamp overtime in rows Labview

Tags: arrays, excel, datetime, labview

How do I display multiple data with respect to my timestamp in array form and written on my excel file?
I have 3 signal randomly generated, I wan to display these signal overtime when I met a certain condition and my vi will start writing them in a array (row) format and display in my excel file.

Eg: x=3 y=4 z=5
when x+y+z > 10
the system will start writing x,y and z with respect to the timestamp, once user click stop or any button it will display in a excel format with few lines of row displaying:
Time/Date x(value) y(value) z(value) total(value)

The one i currently deal with.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you might create the string before writing it to file. If you want to write to file while this loop is executing you'll need to open a file reference outside of the loop, write each line that adds up to 10 or more, then once the loop is done executing close the file reference.[image: Creating a CSV string with a timestamp]